# setup for Spring + hibernate + postgresql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, postgresql

Do someone have a good tutorial for beginner about Spring + hibernate + postgresql(mysql) for mave project? Please shrare.

I found a lot of tutorials on the internet but most (all) of them are out of date. I have been trying to have a right set up for 3 days but can't get it right. So sad, now I dont know which one is the right one to follow :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the guides at http://spring.io/guides -- In particular Spring Boot should simplify set up.

Comment: Thank you stivlo, I have been reading those documents for a couple days. There are a lot of concepts and terminologies that I try to understand, and the best way to learn those is study+practice (I think); But there are so much xml files that I couldnt understand of

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way from a development perspective is to use Spring Boot like `@stivlo` said.  Spring Boot allows you to quickly start a project using various Spring projects and create a data aware Java application fairly quickly.  If you are however looking to learn the stack by diving into the details, you should go through the guides and project documentation.

In simple terms, if you wish to create a data-driven app using Spring, you will be better off using Spring Data and its child projects along with Spring Core.  In general, you can use the following technologies to ease development:

1. Spring Core for dependency injection, aspect-oriented programming and so on;
2. Spring Data JPA for connectivity to an RDBMS;
3. Spring Transactions for transaction management.

The most common development workflow with this stack will be:

1. Model domain entities as JPA entity classes.
2. Generate a data access layer using interfaces extending `JpaRepository` for out-of-the-box database connectivity.
3. Develop a service or business logic layer to orchestrate the data access layer and apply business rules.
4. Develop consumer apps on top of the code developed so far.  These could be a web layer, a REST API, a SOAP interface, etc.
5. Wire everything up with Spring configuration (can be done via Java classes or XML files).

A sample app is [available on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-caching).  It has the following:

1. One domain entity called `org.example.domain.Person`.
2. One data access interface called `org.example.data.PersonRepository`.
3. One business logic class called `org.example.service.PersonService`.
4. One consumer class called `org.example.web.PersonController`.
5. Spring configuration files `springDataContext.xml`, `springServiceContext.xml` and `springWebContext.xml`.  These could have been one file but have been created as separate files to allow finer control over how Spring handles managed components in each layer.

The app uses Scala as the programming language for brevity of code but the equivalent Java code will be similar.  Hibernate is used as the persistence provider and an H2 in-memory database as the persistence store.  These can be easily substituted with other appropriate alternatives through the configuration in `springDataContext.xml` without making any changes to the compiled code.

You can tweak any part of this app to suit specific needs, such as, getting rid of Spring Data JPA and replacing it with the Spring `JdbcTemplate` for hand-coded SQL and such.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for a very simple example of how you can use **MySQL** in a **Sping Boot** web application (with JPA+Hibernate): http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/08/17/use-mysql-database-in-a-spring-boot-web-application-through-hibernate/

You should add the following dependencies in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Set the db configurations in the `application.properties` file:

```
# Database
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/coderpills
db.username: root
db.password: root

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
entitymanager.packagesToScan: coderpills
```

Create a Spring configuration java class (e.g. `DatabaseConfig.java`):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Value("${db.driver}")
  private String DB_DRIVER;

  @Value("${db.password}")
  private String DB_PASSWORD;

  @Value("${db.url}")
  private String DB_URL;

  @Value("${db.username}")
  private String DB_USERNAME;

  @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

  @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

  @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
  private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

  @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
  private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

}
```

Then you can create an entity class, for example an `User` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public long id;

  @NotNull
  public String email;

  @NotNull
  public String name;

  public User() { }

  public User(long id) { 
    this.id = id;
  }

  public User(String email, String name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

with its DAO object:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDao {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory _sessionFactory;

  private Session getSession() {
    return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  public void save(User user) {
    getSession().save(user);
  }

  // Other methods
  // ...

}
```

And finally you can use the DAO object inside your controller autowiring it:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserDao _userDao;

  // You can use the UserDao methods in this controller
  // ...

}
```

Should not be difficult to modify the above example code to make a connection with PostgresSQL instead of MySQL.